# Ignore package in update manager

Tags: package-management, apt, update-manager

I don't want to update certain packages. But this list of packages appears every time I open update manager. Is there an ignore list feature for packages? So I can add or remove packages from ignore list whenever I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then you need to do an apt-pinning, to prevent future updates:

Create a new file in /etc/apt/preferences.d/ (if Ubuntu >= 10.4) named after your program, with following entry:

```
Package: program
Pin: version 1.2.3*
Pin-Priority: 1000
```

assuming, you know that your programs version, you want to freeze, is 1.2.3

Comment: Is there no GUI based update manager? For example, Linux Mint update manager supports this feature

Comment: Yes, I looked, and in `Synaptic packagemanagement` (translation by hand from a german system) you mark a package, then in the menu `package` you can `lock version`.

Comment: @user: Thanks. I know that. I just want some shortcut way (as i mentioned before like linux mint update manager) to do that. An update manager which can ignore some packages

Comment: What do you mean, by 'shortcut way'? You select the package, which you need to select on mint too, I guess. From there it is I don't have linux mint, so your description 'like in linux mint' isn't helpful for me - you have to say, how it is.

Comment: @user: In Linux Mint, when update manager showing the package list, you right click on a package and select "Ignore this package", the package will be in Ignored Package List. Update manager will never show it on update list. If you wish to update that package again, just go to "Ignored List" and remove the package. See, no need to open synaptic, just everything in the update manager.

Comment: Sorry - connection went away while editing. My sentence should have been `From there it is two clicks to lock a version, or to force a specific version.` I don't know how often you lock or unlock versions, that using synaptic seems such an inappropriate indirection. But if you feel so, I guess "No, no such shortcut" is the right answer.

Answer (score 3):

1 - Go to **Synaptic Package Manager**

2 - Enter [package name] into the search field

3 - Highlight the installed package

4 - Click on **Package** on the top row

5 - Select **Lock Version**

Done, now [package name] will no longer be updated.

Comment: >[Lock version is not as clever as it sounds](http://askubuntu.com/a/9615/34756). It's supposed to
>do what it says on the tin, lock the version... But it only
>locks it within Synaptic. Anything else that does package
>upgrades (read: Update Manager, apt-get, aptitude, etc)
>ignores this.



(That's supposed to be a [blockquote](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help#link-simple-blockquotes), I but it doesn't seem to work.)

Answer (score 0):

For KUbuntu:

1. Run "Muon Package Manager"

   - Found under the "start menu" or by running "`muon`" on the command line.
2. Search for the packages you want to lock.
3. Right click on the package and select "Lock at current version".