# I need Mercurial 1.8.x back

Tags: ppa, downgrade, mercurial

I'm getting Mercurial from this PPA: https://launchpad.net/~mercurial-ppa/+archive/releases/+packages?field.name_filter=mercurial&field.status_filter=&field.series_filter=

The Eclipse plugin MercurialEclipse (former HgEclipse) doesn't work well with version 1.9.0. How do I downgrade to 1.8.4?

I tried to [follow the instructions here](http://kubuntuforums.net/forums/index.php?topic=3117253.0) but `aptitude versions mercurial` only lists 1.9.0. When I try `aptitude install mercurial=1.8.4-0ppa1`, I get:

```
Unable to find a version "1.8.4-0ppa1" for the package "mercurial"
```

I'm on Ubuntu 11.04 (Natty).

**[EDIT]** Note that the official version (1.7.5 for Natty) is too old. I need something from the 1.8 range.

Comment: The instructions page is down, but nevertheless, can you see the package if you run `sudo apt-cache search mercurial`?

Comment: Yes, I just can't select any `Superseded` version for installation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the PPA page you can see `1.8.4` is marked as "Superseded". This means it's no longer provided by the repository. That's the reason `aptitude versions mercurial` isn't behaving as you'd want.

You have some options:

1. **Update:** The files are still available through Launchpad. [You can find the built files here](https://launchpad.net/~mercurial-ppa/+archive/releases/+sourcepub/1754980/+listing-archive-extra). Download the debs you want. I suggest you remove the PPA at this point (per point 3) and then manually install the debs.

   [image]
2. Keep using 1.9.x
3. Install `ppa-purge` and purge the PPA, so you're back on `1.7.5`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
   sudo ppa-purge ppa:mercurial-ppa/ppa # or something like that
   ```
4. As #3 but then find another PPA that provides 1.8.5. I suggest if you do ever find a PPA, unless it specifically says it's going to provide 1.8 eternally, that you go on to [lock the version of the packages it installs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9607/what-does-lock-version-do).
5. Do it yourself. Remove everything you have, purging the PPA then: download the source for 1.8, compile it, package it (`checkinstall` should help you there), install it and lock it.

Comment: Damn ... I was too slow and now, the files vanished :-(

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using ppa-purge, you can also do the same thing manually:

1. Remove the offending ppa from the sources list:

   `sudo apt-add-repository -r ppa:mercurial-ppa/ppa`

   (The `-r` removes the ppa)
2. Run `sudo apt-get update`
3. Remove old mercurial version:

   `sudo apt-get remove mercurial mercurial-common`
4. Install mercurial again (for natty, this will be 1.7.5):

   `sudo apt-get install mercurial mercurial-common`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In my case, this isn't useful because 1.7.x is too old for my purposes. But maybe it'll be useful for someone else.