# How to tell Software Updater that I don't want certain updates

Tags: firefox, thunderbird, software-updater

Every day I go on my laptop and Software Updater comes up; it wants me to install Firefox and Thunderbird, which I don't want to do. I'll uncheck those (and the related options) and just install all the other updates. But then, the next day, they'll come up again. Is there any way to tell software updater that I **never** want to do those specific updates/installs?

Comment: check this http://askubuntu.com/questions/9607/what-does-lock-version-do

Comment: @jorgehsrama But something isn't being upgraded; I don't have Firefox or Thunderbird installed already, Ubuntu just wants me to install them. Does this matter?

Comment: Oh sorry, I misread your post. I thought you just didn't want to update them for some reason. Firefox and Thunderbird are default applications, so that's probably why it is always trying to install them.