# How to turn off update for Wireless card

Tags: 12.10, wireless, hardware

I'am a new Linux Ubuntu user my version is 12.10. After updating the OS my wireless turned off, becouse I use Linux for 10 days I dont know how to fix it. Then I reinstalled Linux and want to ask you is there a way to use the updater but Without installing new drivers for wlan or other hardware.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if 12.10 has synaptic, if it doesn't, you can `sudo apt-get install synaptic`. Here are some alternatives I can think of:

1. Go to the synaptic package manager. `Settings > Repositories > Updates`, check `Only notify me about updates`. Then, when you see the `Updates available` icon, click it and only check the updates you want to install -- don't check the drivers update. This works in Debian, it should work on Ubuntu too, although I'm not sure what process manages updates.
2. On synaptic, find the driver's packages, check them, `Edit > Lock Version`. Apparently this won't prevent `aptitude` and `apt-get` of installing new versions, so check [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9607/what-does-lock-version-do) answer.

I only noticed after I answered it, but I think your question is a duplicate of [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18654/how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package).

Comment: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/515/selection001k.png/                 so i should just uncheck this propiretary drivers things

Comment: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/834/selection002q.png/

Comment: If you don't want the updates for whatever driver is that you are talking about just click on `Details for Updates` and uncheck the driver.

Comment: ok thx for help..... but now i got a bigger problem -.-',  I didnt updated just deleted the libre 3.something and installed the 4. after restart i cant see MY wireless network, but i can see my neighbours @_@... damn this wireless problems on ubuntu creep me out

Comment: i know this is a stupid question but can i somehow chat with some of you, so you can explain me some things plz

Comment: There's a chat but a certain amount of reputation is needed. For live chat specially for Ubuntu support check the [IRC](http://www.ubuntu.com/support/community) channel, #ubuntu @ irc.freenode.net